# How can I save password,when using SCP (copy)?

Tags: scripting, scp

I'm facing problem when I pull a file from another machine to my machine using SCP. File is successfully transferred but each time it asks for password. I want to run this `SCP` command as a `cronjob`, How can I save password for this automation?

```
scp user@abc.com:/usr/etc/Output/*.txt /usr/abc/  
user@abc.com's password:
```

Answer (score 26):

You can do:

1. (*if not already done*) generate a set of public and private ssh keys on your machine for your user with:

   `$ ssh-keygen`

   Answer the questions in order to generate the set of keys.
2. copy your public key to the remote host:

   `$ ssh-copy-id remote-user@remote-host`

   This will enable login-in from your `username@host` to `remote-user@remote-host` without being prompt with p/w authentication.

Comment: what do you mean in step 2?  you mean to copy the created file in step one to the machine from which I want to copy a file

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy, `ssh-copy-id` will take care of copying the encrypted credentials onto the remote host, that way it won't prompt for p/w next time that user `ssh` onto it.

Answer (score 9):

you can use this:
`sshpass -p 'your_password' scp user@abc.com:/usr/etc/Output/*.txt /usr/abc/`
but remember that you store password in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

My version of ssh-copy-id requires '-i' option to work, or else it will assume copying credentials from ssh-agent, which will not work if you are not using it.

```
ssh-copy-id -i $myfile.pub remote-user@remote-host
```